# Laravel register form

Tags: sql, laravel

I am trying to add a last name field to my laravel auth register form. But when i try to register i get the error:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'lastname' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (test, test@test.com, $2y$10$lbM5vyBZgu8jjQ5z9jc9F.bhZHXAEeEOyIMno.Onh59//iDDSTNnu, 2020-05-06 09:26:25, 2020-05-06 09:26:25))

This is the code of the last name field:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="lastname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Last name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="lastname" type="text" class="form-control @error('lastname') is-invalid @enderror" name="lastname" value="{{ old('lastname') }}" required autocomplete="lastname" autofocus>

                                @error('LastName')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

And this is the code of my RegisterContoller:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'lastname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: could you add `print_r($data); exit();` in the first line of create function.? And let me know what that $data holds.

Comment: Also Show your User model as well

Comment: This is what i get when i add print_r($data); exit(); to my create function:  Array ( [_token] => KWwsNXwCyiNxklBAoB4ziFiu6y2AP7aUywdMhYYR [name] => test [lastname] => testLastName [email] => test@test.com [password] => Wachtwoord123 [password_confirmation] => Wachtwoord123 ) @Saroj Shrestha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `lastname` is not a default on the User model, you should add it as a fillable property.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

...
protected $fillable = [
   'name', 'lastname', 'email', 'password',
];

...

}
```

You should also set the field as `nullable()` in your migration, if the last name is to be optional.

Comment: Should i add this to my RegisterController or  UserSettings, and when i do should i call on $fillable instead of $data? I'm sorry i am still new to Laravel and trying to learn

Comment: Never mind i just found out what you meant, thank you so much!